# Tooling WSDL in Visual Studio Web Reference

Tags: tooling-api, spring17

I am attempting to do web reference of Tooling WSDL in MS Visual studio but I am unable to do so. I am getting below error:
[image]

Is there any fix?
I have tried it in different version of MS Visual Studio but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to modify the namespace of AuraDefinitionBundle to get it to import correctly with the Spring '17 (v39.0) Tooling API WSDL.

Under `<xsd:complexType name="AuraDefinition">`

Change

```
 <xsd:element name="AuraDefinitionBundle" minOccurs="0" type="ens:AuraDefinitionBundle" nillable="true"/>
```

To:

```
 <xsd:element name="AuraDefinitionBundle" minOccurs="0" type="mns:AuraDefinitionBundle" nillable="true"/>
```

All I did was move the AuraDefinitionBundle from the `ens` ("urn:sobject.tooling.soap.sforce.com") to `mns` ("urn:metadata.tooling.soap.sforce.com") namespace.

---

Generally speaking the Tooling API is full of all sorts of fun oddities.

One of the best is the usage of `xsd:import` at the start of each schema. Essentially each Namespace imports the other two. It creates all sorts of problems with name conflicts with strongly typed languages.

**What the xsd:imports look like in the Tooling API wsdl**
[image: Tooling API xsd:imports]

See also:

- [Salesforce Tooling API Winter '17 (v38.0)](http://www.fishofprey.com/2016/10/salesforce-tooling-api-winter-17-v380.html)

Comment: WOW just work like a charm.